# Is general relativity a background dependent theory in five dimensions?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime-dimensions

I read the article [What is a background-free theory?](http://god-does-not-play-dice.net/background.html) by John Baez and was wondering that if I add a fifth dimension to a background independent theory like general relativity I get a background dependent theory like the Maxwell's equations. The only difference: In Maxwell's equations you have electromagnetic fields. In five dimensions you have spacetime fields,- or spacetime-fluidflows or whatever you want to call it.
I couldn't find good arguments against or in favor of this viewpoint.

Answer (score 1):

By a five-dimensional extension of general relativity that unifies it with electromagnetism, you presumably mean [Kaluza-Klein theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza%E2%80%93Klein_theory) or something very similar. As explained [here](http://what-when-how.com/string-theory/kaluza-klein-theory-%E2%80%94-string-theorys-predecessor/), K-K is indeed background-dependent; as with string theory decades later, this is considered a problem.

Comment: Thanks I will read through the mentioned article. 
_"..., this is considered a problem."_ I read exactly the same thing multiple times. Also related to the string theory view of quantum gravity. For example in: Making Starships and Stargates, James F. Woodward expressed the same concerns, that the string theory gravity view, is not background-independent? But then if you can draw/embed a 2d wormhole in flat 3 dimensions, why can't you draw a 4d wormhole in 5 dimensions? Also teleparallel gravity seems to indicate that the answer is not as easy as it may appear at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

A background consists of non-dynamical data for a theory. E.g. for [field theories in curved spacetimes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory_in_curved_spacetime), the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ is a non-dynamical fixed background. In contract, for general relativity in any spacetime dimension, the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ is a dynamically active field, and hence not a background.

For the notion of background-independence, see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_independence).